# WPAlchemy Meta Box: Place meta box on specific post / page... conflict with "types" argument

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm using the WPAlchemy class to create a metabox. I want to place this metabox in a number of post editors in the backend.

Currently it's working just fine with the following code:

```
$video_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_videoMeta',
    'title' => 'Videos',    
    'types' => array('characters','homepage'),
    'template' => THEMEASSETS . '/functions/video_meta.php'
));
```

What I want to do though is additionally place the metabox on the post editor for post ID #22. Supposedly the following code should work:

```
$video_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_videoMeta',
    'title' => 'Videos',    
    'types' => array('characters','homepage'),
    'template' => THEMEASSETS . '/functions/video_meta.php',
    'include_post_id' => 22
));
```

But it doesn't work unless I add in 'page' into the array of post types, which adds the metabox to *all* pages (not just post ID 22).

Is there a way to use poth the types *and* the include post ID arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Acutally, I had set a metabox to two custom post types and wanted it to be displayed on a specific page.

```
$video_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
'id' => '_videoMeta',
'title' => 'Videos',    
'types' => array('characters','homepage', 'page'),
'template' => THEMEASSETS . '/functions/video_meta.php',
'include_post_id' => 22
));
```

Just add the bult in 'page' post type and everything should work fine. It did for me.